# Combining two or more estUDm objects into a single estUDm object

Tags: r, spatial, overlap, adehabitathr

I know it is possible to combine multiple estUD objects into a single class-estUDm object using:

```
tot <- list(estUD1=estUD1, estUD2=estUD2, estUD3=estUD3)
class(tot) <- "estUDm"
```

However, is it possible to combine two or more **estUDm** objects into a single estUDm object? I have tried using the same principle; i.e.

```
tot <- list(estUDm1=estUDm1, estUDm2=estUDm2, estUDm3=estUDm3)
class(tot) <- "estUDm"
```

however, this results in the following error :

```
> tot
********** Utilization distribution of several Animals ************

Error in print.estUDm(x) : 
  trying to get slot "vol" from an object (class "estUDm") that is not an S4 object
```

In my case, my objective is to run two KDE analyses with the same grid, but different smoothers (hence I end up with two estUDm objects), and then combine these to calculate the % overlap of polygons using kerneloverlaphr().

I have unsuccessfully tried to find / create alternative code that can calculate the overlap of multiple polygons in one go, hence my reliance on kerneloverlaphr().

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but because class-estUDm is just a list of class-estUD, I believe you can unlist to obtain class-estUD, concatenate these into a new list, then specify the estUDm class. An example below.

```
library(adehabitatHR)
library(sp)

#example data
data(puechabonsp)
dat <- puechabonsp$relocs
dat$Name <- as.character(dat$Name)

#split into two datasets
d1 <- dat[dat$Name == 'Brock' | dat$Name == 'Jean', ]
d2 <- dat[dat$Name != 'Brock' & dat$Name != 'Jean', ]

#get two lists of class estUDm
estUDm1 <- kernelUD(d1[ ,'Name'])
estUDm2 <- kernelUD(d2[ ,'Name'])

#unlist for class estuD
estUDm1 <- unlist(estUDm1)
estUDm2 <- unlist(estUDm2)

#concatenate to a new list
tot <- c(estUDm1, estUDm2)

#assign class estuDm
class(tot) <- "estUDm"
tot
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Ben. While your answer may solve the OP's issue, it's not possible to tell as you haven't provided a sample input and output. To make your answer more helpful to others, please consider making it reproducible. Thanks

Comment: You're right, thank you. I've provided an example.